# MERN путь до папки uploads?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

использую стек Mern. При добавлении товара , фотография загружается в корневой папке проекта /uploads.
Каким образом на стороне frontend'a ( react) получить путь к изображению? Пробовал написать localhost:5000/uploads( сервер на 5000 порту ) но 404

Comment: `app.use(express.static('uploads'));`

Comment: @nörbörnën http://localhost:5000/uploads/product/photo1604898801703-659815029.jpg Тогда путь в src должен быть таким?

Comment: про структуру вашего файлового хранилища вы пишете: `фотография загружается в корневой папке проекта /uploads`, если это так то ссылка должна выглядеть как localhost:5000/uploads/photo1604898801703-659815029.jpg. это в простейшем случае. далее - можно почитать [документацию](https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html) и сделать красивее `app.use('/product', express.static('uploads'));` и тогда картинка будет доступна по ссылке localhost:5000/product/photo1604898801703-659815029.jpg

Comment: @nörbörnën Прошу прощения неправильно изначально описал
У меня следующий каталог
./uploads/product 

Я добавил такую строчку app.use(express.static('./uploads/product'));

Но к примеру такой src выдает 404 
http://localhost:5000/uploads/product/photo1604907912124-531241236.jpg

Comment: для начала попробуйте `app.use(express.static('uploads'));` и запрос http://localhost:5000/uploads/product/photo1604898801703-659815029.jpg

Comment: @nörbörnën К сожалению никак не работает. Все же выдает 404 , можно ли как то дебажить данный момент?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115983/discussion-between-daniel-qwaqwaqwa-and-norbornen).